# URL to use when deploying pyroscope to K8s in microservice mode

Tags: grafana

Should I use the URL of the distributor to write the data?

Should I use the query-frontend URL for the URL used to read the data?

I have looked at the following doc, but it is not clearly mentioned.
https://grafana.com/docs/pyroscope/latest/deploy-kubernetes/helm/

It looks like querier is used in the loading URL, but looking at this architecture, it seems correct to use query-frontend.
https://grafana.com/docs/pyroscope/latest/reference-pyroscope-architecture/about-grafana-pyroscope-architecture/